# Error : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I would like to calculate the total number of lines for a particular support option where the lines are from two tables as CSPLineItem and SupportOption. I'm using below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT sot.SupportOptionType_ID,
    (Classic.NumberOfLines + MEN.NumberOfLines) TotalNumberOfLines
FROM SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sot.SupportOptionType_ID,
        COUNT(li.CSPLineItem_ID) NumberOfLines
    FROM CSPLineItem li WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID = li.SupportOptionType_ID
    GROUP BY sot.SupportOptionType_ID
    ) Classic
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sot.SupportOptionType_ID,
        COUNT(so.SupportOption_ID) NumberOfLines
    FROM SupportOption so WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID = so.SupportOptionType_ID
    GROUP BY sot.SupportOptionType_ID
    ) MEN
```

But I'm getting below error near last line:

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Anybody please help out.

Comment: You're not joining the two tables together. IE: -> )MEN ON MEN.SupportOptionType_ID = Classic.SupportOptionType_ID

Comment: You're doing `LEFT JOIN`s on your subqueries but haven't specified `ON` clauses for them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in an ON clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sot.SupportOptionType_ID, (Classic.NumberOfLines + MEN.NumberOfLines) TotalNumberOfLines
FROM SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  sot.SupportOptionType_ID,COUNT(li.CSPLineItem_ID) NumberOfLines
FROM CSPLineItem li WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK) ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID = li.SupportOptionType_ID
GROUP BY sot.SupportOptionType_ID
) Classic
ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID=Classic.SupportOptionType_ID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  sot.SupportOptionType_ID,COUNT(so.SupportOption_ID) NumberOfLines
FROM SupportOption so WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK) ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID = so.SupportOptionType_ID
GROUP BY sot.SupportOptionType_ID
)MEN
ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID=MEN.SupportOptionType_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct sot.SupportOptionType_ID, (Classic.NumberOfLines + MEN.NumberOfLines) TotalNumberOfLines
FROM SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  sot.SupportOptionType_ID,COUNT(li.CSPLineItem_ID) NumberOfLines
FROM CSPLineItem li WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK) ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID = li.SupportOptionType_ID
GROUP BY sot.SupportOptionType_ID
) Classic
on sot.SupportOptionType_ID=Classic.SupportOptionType_ID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  sot.SupportOptionType_ID,COUNT(so.SupportOption_ID) NumberOfLines
FROM SupportOption so WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN SupportOptionType sot WITH (NOLOCK) ON sot.SupportOptionType_ID = so.SupportOptionType_ID
GROUP BY sot.SupportOptionType_ID
)MEN
on sot.SupportOptionType_ID=MEN.SupportOptionType_ID
```